# Перегрузка операции сравнения для структур

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Имеется структура:

```
struct Point3D
{
    int x, y, z;
};
```

Как тут можно перегрузить оператор сравнения, что бы вместо

```
if(p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y && p1.z == p2.z)
```

можно было написать

```
if(p1 == p2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну собственно вы почти все и написали.

Перегружаем оператор сравнения и вставляем туда ваш код из первого if'а

```
bool operator == (const Point3D &point) const {
   return this->x == point.x && this->y == point.y && this->z == point.z;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Например, так

```
bool operator== (const Point3D& rl) {
    if (&rl == this) return true;
    return (this->x==rl.x) && (this->y==rl.y) && (this->z==rl.z);
}
```